# How to enter PIN for X509Certificate2 certificate programmatically when signing a PDF (in C#)

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, x509certificate2

I'm using syncfusion pdf to for digitally signing pdf files. On their website, they have an example for external signing a PDF. I slightly  changed the example so the certificate can be selected from the windows certificate store. The selected certificate requires a PIN, so that a dialog pop up. The function Signature_ComputeHast is plain C# code. How can I enter the PIN programmatically in the code below?

Original example: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-digitalsignature#externally-sing-a-pdf-document

```
       private static X509Certificate2 SelectCertificate()
        {
            // Selecte certificate from store
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection selectedCertificate = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false);// (X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, true);
            selectedCertificate = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
            store.Certificates,
            "Certficates",
            "Select a certificate for signing the document",
            X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
            return selectedCertificate[0];
        }


void Signature_ComputeHash(object sender, PdfSignatureEventArgs arguments)

        {
            //Get the document bytes
            byte[] documentBytes = arguments.Data;
            SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(documentBytes), detached: true);
            //Compute the signature using the specified digital ID file and the password
            X509Certificate2 certificate = SelectCertificate();
            var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(certificate);
            //Set the digest algorithm SHA256
            cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
            signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
            //Embed the encoded digital signature to the PDF document
            arguments.SignedData = signedCms.Encode();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the RSACryptoServiceProvider or RSACng cng (in .NET core) classes which support Hardware Security Modules to a greater level of granularity on Windows. You can create a new instance of the appropriate class with parameters to include the password as follows:

```
        if(certificate.PrivateKey is RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa) {
            if(rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice) {
                CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters(1, rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
                    rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName) {
                    KeyPassword = certPassword,
                    Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt
                };
                byte[] signedCMSBytes = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams).SignData(documentBytesDigest);
            }
        }
```

As far as I am aware you will need to create the hashed digest of documentBytes digest and put that in the in PKCS#7 along with the desired authenticated attributes yourself prior to signing. After that you will need to add any unauthenticated attributes to the CMS. Personally I do all that using Bouncy Castle. But we have to use the MS SSC to interact with the OS for access to the HSM. There is potentially a way to do it all with the SSC classes. Incidentally certPassword is a SecureString.